Staging Ground - Unable to paste images into editor
On Staging Ground, when editing/creating a question, using the editor, there seems to be a bug, with regard to pasting images. When clicking on the image button/icon in the toolbar, and the "Browse, drag & drop, or paste an image" text appears, the word "paste" does not appear as a hyperlink, as should be expected, in order to allow one clicking on it and pasting an image link.

I'm able to paste, but only using hotkeys, and only after selecting the area that pops up after pressing the image button (which doesn't select on opening)

@ErikA: using hotkeys "works", but  the result is e.g. [![enter image description here](https://image.png)], not [![enter image description here][1]][1] with [1]: https://image.png as one normally gets. Also just noting that the text in the frame is different ("paste an image" vs "paste an image or link"). Same goes for the "supported file types" line underneath. As far as I can tell, all other occurrences of this "Images" icon seem linked to the exact same functionality.
